# How to connect Kibana with Elastic Enterprise Search in Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elastic-stack, kubernetes-pod, elk

I have deployed Elasticsearch, Kibana and Enterprise Search to my local Kubernetes Cluster [via this official guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-orchestrating-elastic-stack-applications.html) and they are working fine individually (and are connected to the Elasticsearch instance).

Now I wanted to setup Kibana to connect with Enterprise search like this:

[image]

I tried it with localhost, but that obviously did not work in Kubernetes.
So I tried the service name inside Kubernetes, but now I am getting this error:

[image]

The Log from Kubernetes is the following:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2021-01-15T15:18:48Z","tags":["error","plugins","enterpriseSearch"],"pid":8,"message":"Could not perform access check to Enterprise Search: FetchError: request to https://enterprise-search-quickstart-ent-http.svc:3002/api/ent/v2/internal/client_config failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND enterprise-search-quickstart-ent-http.svc enterprise-search-quickstart-ent-http.svc:3002"}
```

So the questions is how do I configure my kibana `enterpriseSearch.host` so that it will work?

Here are my deployment yaml files:

```
# Kibana
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.10.1
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: quickstart
  config:
    enterpriseSearch.host: 'https://enterprise-search-quickstart-ent-http.svc:3002'

# Enterprise Search
apiVersion: enterprisesearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: EnterpriseSearch
metadata:
  name: enterprise-search-quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.10.1
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: quickstart
  config:
    ent_search.external_url: https://localhost:3002
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered quite the same issue, but on a development environment based on docker-compose.

I fixed it by setting `ent_search.external_url` value the same as `enterpriseSearch.host` value

In your case, i guess, your 'Enterprise Search' deployment yaml file should look like this :

```
# Enterprise Search
apiVersion: enterprisesearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1beta1
kind: EnterpriseSearch
metadata:
  name: enterprise-search-quickstart
spec:
  version: 7.10.1
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: quickstart
  config:
    ent_search.external_url: 'https://enterprise-search-quickstart-ent-http.svc:3002'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My issue is not with Enterprise Search, but with Kibana not connecting to Enterprise Search. The `ent_search.external_url` is just the outside address of the enterprise search UI - as far as I know. I am looking for the right `enterpriseSearch.host` value.

Comment: Did you try to make those 2 parameters match ?

Comment: Yep, tried it out just now. Same result, can't connect.

Comment: Seems like the `metadata.name` has to mach the one of the kibana deployment. I am getting an ssl error now. Thanks for the idea with matching parameters!